# How can I capture the screens from an application from within a different application?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I currently have some code in a program that captures all of the screens open in that program. There is a separate executable that this program opens that handles some pdf editing and printing and I want to also capture the windows from this separate program when it is open. How can I do this?

Here is what I tried so far, but I don't know how to get all of the windows associated with the process:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");
if (processes.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        //do something to grab the associated windows.
    }
}
```

Comment: There is `MainWindowHandle` property exposed by `Process` class.

Comment: Doesn't `MainWindowHandle` only give you the Main Window associated with the process. What if there are multiple windows?